# How to get timezone from DateTimeZone Object in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, timezone

how i get timezone from Datetime object PHP?

```
<pre>DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Comment: Are you simply looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getname.php, or what? (And if you are, then why _didn’t_ you actually?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$webhookNotification->subscription->billingPeriodStartDate->getTimezone()->getName()

Answer (score 1):

Try to get a zone object as according the requirements:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne');
```

After reach properties what aimed:

```
$name = $tz->getName();

echo $name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can get by **->**

```
echo $timezone->timezone;
```

Comment: [billingPeriodStartDate] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-07-30 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

Comment: $timezone[billingPeriodStartDate]->timezone;

Comment: This doesn't always work.  $timezone->getName() does.